Escaping double quotations in command line instructions Julia
I want to run some commands in the terminal using libreoffice to convert some .docx files into .pdfs. The code works in the terminal when I can manually place double quotes "...", but when I try to do this programatically from Julia it gets interpreted in the wrong way.
For example, I want my command in the terminal to look like this: (And this works)
"C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.com" --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder" "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\input.docx"

However, when I try to write it like this in Julia:
run(`cmd /c $executable --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir $output_folder $input_path`)

It shows up like this:
'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.com' --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder' 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\input.docx'

And I get the error:
 C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file
I've tried manually typing it in, using ^ escape characters, adding more quotes etc. Any ideas as to how I can keep the double quotes in the final command? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

WFM: Your run command worked for me on Julia 1.10.4, using your string for executable and a simple input document for input_path.

I tried adding quotes around the "$(...)", and escaping them as well, but it gave me an invalid syntax error. @user9712582, Strange, I'm also using Julia 1.10.4. You have the exact same path for the executable and a .docx file?

executable = "C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.com"

I managed to do a workaround with a batch file, but any ideas as to what the difference might be between your situation and mine? I think our code is the same.

One possible cause is a leading space in the executable variable.
For example, in following, executableA runs fine for me, but executableB produces the error.
executableA = "C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.com"
executableB = " C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.com"

run(`cmd /c $executableA --version`)
# LibreOffice 24.2.3.2 433d9c2ded56988e8a90e6b2e771ee4e6a5ab2ba
# 
# Process(`cmd /c 'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.com' --version`, ProcessExited(0))

run(`cmd /c $executableB --version`)
# 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
# ERROR: failed process: Process(`cmd /c ' C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.com' --version`, ProcessExited(1))

